# Compress and encrypt in Delphi

Tags: delphi, encryption, compression

I need a fast and strong compression + encryption method for my `DAT` file.

I've a `DAT` file which contains very sensitive information and I would like to compress and encrypt it. I know I can use Zlib in compression method but how about the encryption method too ?

many thanks

Comment: Searching for Delphi Encryption Component gives some results http://www.google.ie/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=delphi+encryption+component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need both encryption and compression at the same time, you have two ways of implementing it:

- Use your data in a memory buffer, then compress this buffer, then encrypt it;
- Use streams, one for compression, the other for encryption.

In all cases, the best is to compress before encryption. It is more difficult to uncypher data from a compressed format, since its content is less expectable.

Then rely on a strong enough encryption algorithm (like AES).

You have all those features in our Open Source units (from Delphi 5 up to XE2). You can use ZIP, or try our much faster (but less efficient in term of compression ration) [SynLZ](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/06/26/Pure-pascal-LZO-and-SynLZ-compression-units). Then [SynCrypto](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynCrypto.pas) can be used to encrypt it. There are direct functions handling `RawByteString` kind of data, which contents the data in a memory buffer.

Comment: Can you compress and encrypt a 5 gb file with SynLZ?  It seems limited by the amount of memory available to hold a string, unless one is supposed to load a certain amount into memory, compress it, and then write that?

Answer (score 6):

Please check out the [Delphi Encryption Compendium](http://code.google.com/p/delphidec/) (aka DEC):

Comment: i know DEC , but what i want to acheive is :
Compress + encrypt at same time ( not only Compress or Encrypt )
thank you

Comment: I would compress and then encrypt, these are 2 separate stages.

Comment: These stages do not require you to output an interim file to disk, if you use streams in memory.

Comment: If your compression method includes a header with a known signature, I would encrypt first, then compress. Reverse encryption when you know the first bit is much easier to automate through brute force.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: you can't compress the output of any decent encryption algorithm

Comment: @GregS, I see what you're saying, you won't get much compression since the data is fairly randomly distributed, so, use some form of stream compression without a header or known signature, or use a large enough key size that brute force is not even a concern.

Answer (score 6):

Another much used component is DCPCrypt:

http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/dcpcrypt

It is stream based, so you can layer compression and encryption. I don't know code that does it in one step. (at least not with sensible encryption)

Comment: I have used this heavily.  Because streams can be composed (layered) easily, I can even put multiple layers of encryption on with very little effort.  How about you use ZLIB streams then output that strem to an AES encryption stream? Streams are key to compression +1 encryption on top.  It's not one step or multiple steps, it's a stream, and you need a pump loop per layer, and you don't need to write any temporary zip file that is not encrypted to disk.

Comment: And e.g. stuff like base64 en/decoding, which was my exact case.

Comment: The one time I tried to use DCPCrypt for Blowfish, it wasn't matching the PHP implementations. I don't know if it was me, but you'll want to make sure it matches other implementations so that you're not locked in.

Comment: DCPCrypt can be finicky about details, to enable full control over the cypher. Properly initializing and finalizing (e.g. invert in CRC32) the cypher/hash can be important. Hastily converted code is often wrong